# invariant space and eigenvector

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $V$ be a finite-dimensional vector space over $C$, let $T:V\rightarrow V$ be a linear operator, and let $M$ be a nontrivial subspace of $V$ that is invariant under $T$. Prove that $M$ contains an eigenvector of T.
I am trying to find the eigenvector, but I can not.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**: As $M$ is $T$-invariant, we may consider $T|_M \colon M \to M$, now $T|_M$ is an endomorphism of a non-trivial $\mathbb C$-vector space. What can you say about eigenvectors of $T|_M$?

Comment: You mean from $TM=M$, then we can get the eigenvetor?

Comment: We may have that $T(M) \subsetneq M$, but this does not matter. The point is, that if $M$ is any finite dimensional complex vector space, and $S \colon M \to M$ is any endomorphism, than $S$ has an eigenvector. Apply this to $S = T|_M$.

Comment: I have one question, why $S$ has an eigenvector if $S:M\rightarrow M$ is endomorphism?

Comment: As $\mathbb C$ is algebraically closed, every polynomial over $\mathbb C$ has a root. Apply this to the characteristic polynomial of $S$.

Comment: Our textbook is <matrix analysis and applied linear algebra>, so something you mentioned above I did not learn. Can you make you idea based on linear algebra?

Comment: That's hardly possible. The fact that every endomorphism of a finite dimensional $\mathbb C$-vector space has an eigenvector is equivalent to the so called "fundamental theorem of algebra". It is more than just linear algebra behind this theorem.

Comment: @user81235 Chapter 7, page 492 of the online version here: http://www.matrixanalysis.com/DownloadChapters.html